# Shader Forge - strange nodes issue

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I'm a complete beginner with the Sader Forge, trying to create a very basic shader, but I have some strange problems with the nodes in the default shader setup:

1. **Texture2D** and **Color** nodes which was created by default with the new shader controlls shader image and color even when disconnected. Newly created nodes doesn't change anything even though they are connected to the Base Color input.
2. The **Normal Map** node doesn't affect anything after I choose the normal map image. When I click "Normal map" the image in the node becomes red.
3. **Sliders** doesn't change shader look.

[image]

Comment: Top left, see the "compile shader" button? Click that. Its yellow because some values changed, but nothing that actually *requires* a recompile, so it hasn't updated the preview (that's why the button is yellow, if it was red, it would recompile automatically because of the [x] auto checkbox being checked).

Comment: @Draco18s Thanks for the reply, yes, I tried it, but it doesn't help. The default nodes still control shader look even when disconnected, the new nodes doesn't affect it even though they are connected to the Main node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so what I can gather...

1. Newly created nodes (you have two at the [top of your screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3Jtq.png)) aren't connected to anything by default. It appears the preview is using these disconnected nodes and not your new ones, I am not sure what is up here. It is possible that this is a bug. Try deleting the bad nodes (all four of them) and recreating them. Try also updating Shader Forge. (I cannot reproduce this behavior)
2. Your normal map *may not be a valid normal map* and so its (nearly perfect) solid color doesn't really *do* anything:
   [image: Comparison]

   - The right is an approximation of your own bump texture, the left is a solid color taken as an average of said texture.
   - Compared to a [real bump map](http://www.bundysoft.com/wiki/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=tutorials:l3dt:bumpmap:rock2_bump.jpg):
     [image: Real bump map]
3. Slider values don't really "update" the shader (they're just values, Shader Forge doesn't treat it as a change to the code, so it doesn't recompile). It should update the preview, provided that those sliders affect something (they [do for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4o75.gif)).